# linking vector of derived class type to vector of parent class type in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector

I am in beginner stage of C++. Suppose I have a base class and a derived class:

```
class Base{
 ....

}

class Derived:public Base{

 ....
}
```

Now I have two vectors as follows, I will perform some operations to some create base and derived objects and push these objects back to their corresponding vectors respectively:

```
std::vector<Base*> baseVector
std::vector<Derived*> derivedVector
```

I want to point each of the element(object) of derivedVector to each of the element(object) of the baseVector. Suppose derivedVector[2] will have a pointer to baseVector[2] so that at any time I can access the base object from my derived object. How should I do this?

Comment: "I want to point each of the element(object) of derivedVector to each of the element(object) of the baseVector."   What do you mean, can you please explain more??

Comment: so you want to store objects in baseVector and pointers in derivedVector?

Comment: @FredrickGauss: I basically want to keep some pointer in derived object so that they can point to the base object.

Comment: your words about object, pointer and vector (base, derived) is complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the important part of your question:

> ... so that at any time I can access the base object from my derived object.

And the answer is fairly simple.  With inheritance, the derived object can already access its base object.  *That's the whole point of inheritance.*

You can keep it simple:

```
class Base{
    SomeBaseFunction();
}

class Derived : public Base{
    // Do not add a Base* here.
}

int main() {
    Derived *derived_object = new Derived();
    derived_object->SomeFunction();  // this works.
}
```

---

You should think more clearly about your `vector`s here.   You probably only need one vector, not two.  Also, you should probably deal with `vector<Derived>`, not `vector<Derived*>`.

```
int main () {
    Derived derived_object;   // don't use `new` here, it's just awkward

    vector<Derived>  vector_of_objects;
    vector_of_objects.push_back(derived_object);
}
```

In modern C++, whether you're a beginner or an expert, you shouldn't use `*` or `new` very often.

Answer (score 3):

It's not very clear what you mean, but if I understand correctly you want to put pointer to your `Derived` object in two vectors. You can achieve it this way:

```
baseVector[2] = derivedVector[2] = new Derived();
```

Answer (score 0):

See if you want to use base list to contain derived object pointers then it is ok. but you can't use derived list to hold base pointers.

may be you want something like.

```
Base * pBase = new Base();
Derived *pDerived_1 = new Derived();
// or
Base *pDerived_2 = (Base *)new Derived();
// this can be anytime casted back
Derived *pDerived_3 = (Derived*)pDerived_2;

// you can also push them into base vector
lstBasePtr.push_back(pBase);
lstBasePtr.push_back(pDerived_1);
lstBasePtr.push_back(pDerived_2);
lstBasePtr.push_back(pDerived_3);
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi thanks for your response. I have figured out what I needed to do. Not sure if its the smartest way, if not please suggest me.

Here is how I did it:

```
class Base{
    SomeBaseFunction();

}

class Derived:public base{
//I have put a pointer of base type here 
base *basePointer;
}
```

Now in the main function where I basically populate the base and derived vector, I do the following:

```
derivedObject->basePointer = baseObject;
```

Now I can access the base properties as follows:

```
derivedObject->basePointer->SomeBaseFunction();
```

Comment: In this case, you should remove the `:public base`.  You are not actually making use of inheritance in your answer, so you're just confusing yourself if you have `:public base` after `class Derived`.  (You should rename your class from `Derived` to something else if you're not using inheritance).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now its making more sense. I have another question, why I should not use new and *?

Comment: There are cases where `new` is necessary, but `new` is overused.  There are two reasons.  First, code without `new` is usually simpler and easier to read.  You should treat objects, such as `string` or your own objects, the same was you would treat an `int`.  If you want to add 5+7, why write `int *x = new int(5); int *y = new int(7); int *z = new int(*x+*y);`?  It's simpler to just write `int x = 5; int y = 7; int z = x+y`.  It also leads to faster code.  Finally, if you use `new`, there will be times when you forget to `delete` the object and this will leads to bugs and memory leaks.

Comment: thanks for your detailed explanation, but for larger dataset will not using *new* be more memory efficient?

Comment: We should draw a distinction between "memory efficiency" and "speed efficiency".  The method I propose will not use any more memory.  Yes, sometimes objects will be copied, but any unnecessary objects will be deleted automatically.  Therefore, in the long run it won't use up extra memory.  Note, the `new` approach will object lead to memory leaks, and in that case `new` will be the inefficient approach.  As regards speed, it's tempting to say that my approach will be slow "because of all the copying of large objects".  But compilers can optimize many of these copies out (NRVO).   ... continued

Comment: ... (continued).   In many cases in programming, people will make changes "for efficiency" and discover that the changes have actually made the program slower or use more memory!  "Optimization" is a strange art.  The good news is that, if you just write code that is simple and you can read, you'll probably get a correct program, and 'correct' is more important than the illusion of speed.  (And maybe the compiler can "out-optimize" you!)  If you ignore most of my comments here, then just [read this](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/), an excellent blog on the topic.